# How do I to resolve unmet dependencies to uninstall and reinstall package

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, dependencies

I have tried several askubuntu threads but yet to no avail none have all met qualifications.

I installed allvideodownloader, and found a better version an earlier version; I downloaded from software-center, so there should not have been a related programs version problem and I got this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 allvideodownloader : Depends: allvideodownloader-bin (= 2.6.0-0ubuntu1)
 apache2.2-bin : Depends: libaprutil1-ldap but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have tried the usual suspects, in synaptic, software-center and aptitude.

```
 apt-get autoremove --purge allvideodownloader
Package allvideodownloader is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded

 apt-get remove --auto-remove allvideodownloader-bin
Package allvideodownloader is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded

 apt-get remove --auto-remove allvideodownloader-bin
E Unable to locate package allvideoinstaller-bin

 sudo apt-get install allvideoinstaller-bin
E Unable to locate package allvideoinstaller-bin
```

This is what I believe to be so; allvideodownloader changed the versions on several packages at install and didn't change them back at uninstall. These packages are somehow not reverse compatible using usual means.

I am having a headache I am growing used to from staring at this problem and that wont help matters. I've tried manner of install , purge and repair of broken packages

Please advise me on a repair.

thx, 
DL

Comment: what is the output of sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded

Comment: Try `apt-get install -f allvideodownloader` and comment what you get.

Comment: apt-get install -f allvideodownloader returned the same as above, unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to install dependencies, all of them at once, once you figure them all out. From that alone I see you need to `sudo aptitude install allvideodownloader-bin libaprutil1-ldap allvideodownloder` and if that errors it will show more dependencies and you just add those to your command and try again.

Comment: I posted above what that got me. See if you can make hide or tails of it? dl

Comment: You have to install them all at the same time rather than one at a time as indicated above.

Comment: I'll try after a couple of hours sleep, thx, dl

Comment: This worked. I had to do an install/uninstall at one time from the error generated by the above answer, thank you very much.